# In typescript, how do you determine whether another parameter needs to be added based on the previous Boolean parameter?

Tags: typescript-typings, typescript2.0

This is a example

```
const fn = (bool, str1, str2) => {
    // do something
}
```

if bool is true,  str2 needs to be passed in, otherwise not

Comment: make str2 as optional. Then pass str2 on function call when bool is true otherwise don't pass it if bool is false.
const fn = (bool, str1, str2?) => {
    // do something
};
fn(true, 'data1','data2' );
fn(false, 'data1' );

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define overloads like this:

```js
function fn(bool: false, str1: string): void;
function fn(bool: true, str1: string, str2: string): void;
function fn(bool: boolean, str1: string, str2?: string): void {
    // do something
}

fn(false, "a"); // OK
fn(false, "a", "b"); // Error
fn(true, "a"); // Error
fn(true, "a", "b"); // OK
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABMMAKARnOAbAXMgQ2wGcBTAGkWKgCcBGfammMAcwEp8A3OGAEwDcAKFCRYCZGkw58tEBSq0Gi5m0pMATI1osO3XoJHho8JCgxY8iadlIEw6pdtWtHNDQH5nuzoh79EAG8hRFDEAHpwxD44KjgAW1IoAAtdIQBfIRE0YCIySgAiAgL2AQiogHkAaWzUXJIFIoLC9BKyyMQAURoaOBpauUbi0vKunr6BmnlC4pa20eqgA)